# Looking for a well-known idiom, phrase, or expression for "[they] make it into a whole procession"

Tags: phrase-requests

To describe someone carrying out a standard task in an overly elaborate way, with zeal.

Description should be humorous, snarky, taking a jab at the someone who is overcomplicating things.

Etched in my mind is the bookish sounding phrase, "it's a whole procession."

Colloquially, "it's a whole thing with Bob..."? Where, 'it' is perceived by Alice as something which doesn't require so much attention. E.g. shopping for socks.

**Edit:** Thanks everyone! "Making a song and dance out of it" and "rigamarole" are closest to what I was looking for. I could use "pulling out all the stops" too!

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re trying to ask exactly. Could you please edit your question and try to explain the context more clearly? When you say _undertaker_, I take it you’re referring to the person undertaking a task, and not the person whose job it is to arrange funerals and make dead bodies look presentable for open coffins?

Comment: Are you asking about something in the context of funerals—or shopping? Or is there no specific context? The way you've phrased your question makes your requirement unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard idiomatic usage in English doesn't refer to a *procession*. It's...

> [*to **make a song and dance about** [it]*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-make-a-song-and-dance-abou)
>   (Collins Dictionary)
>    *If you say that someone is making a song and dance about something, you mean they are making an unnecessary fuss about it.*

It often occurs in the negative, as in...

> *Going shopping for socks is nothing special. There's no need to make a song and dance about it*

Answer (score 2):

*They* are simply making a ***big deal*** out of it.

> Alice feels that Bob *makes a **big deal*** out of shopping for socks.

TFD(idioms):

> **[big deal](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/big+deal)**
>   **1**. *n*. something really important. Don’t make such a big deal out of it!
>
> McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Slang and Colloquial Expressions
>   Copyright © 2006 by The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc. All rights
>   reserved.

We can also say *they* are *making a **song and dance** about* it.

> Alice feels that Bob is ***making a song and dance about*** shopping for socks.

TFD(idioms):

> **[make a song and ˈdance about something](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+a+song+and+dance+about)** (informal, disapproving)
>   worry or be excited about something which is not very
>   important: My aunt makes a real song and dance about people arriving
>   late, so hurry up.
>
> Farlex Partner Idioms Dictionary © Farlex 2017

Answer (score 2):

Relevant, but perhaps awkward to say that someone makes a *rigamarole* of things.  As both the linked example sentences say, *rigamarole* is endured.

> [***rigamarole***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rigmarole#examples) - a complex and sometimes ritualistic procedure

Answer (score 0):

They're *overcomplicating* things.

> [***overcomplicate***](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/overcomplicate) - to make complex, intricate, involved, or difficult: